# How to change the size of my Text in my plots legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to increase the Textsize in my legend:
[image]

As you can see in the picture, the size of the text is too small. 
Changing cex just increases the whole legend, which doesn't look well.

[image]

Is there a way to increase just the text size in the legend ?

Right now my plot code looks like this:

```
par(font.main=3, font.lab=1, font.sub=1, cex.main=2, cex.lab=1.7, cex.sub=1.2)

plot(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`12.2`)),type="l",col="blue",main="Momentum-Performance Deutschland",ylab="Portfolio Wert",xlab="Jahr",ylim=c(-0.5,2.5),yaxt ="n"
 ,cex.main=1.5,cex.lab=1,cex.axis=1)
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`12.7`)),type="l",col="green")
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`6.2`)),type="l",col="red")
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$Markt)),type="l",col="yellow")
legend("topleft",legend = c("12-2","12-7","6-2","Markt"),col =     c("blue","green","red","yellow"),adj = c(0, 0.5),pt.cex = cex,lty=1,   cex=1,bg="grey",y.intersp = 0.8,x.intersp = 1.2)
axis(2, at=seq(0,2,by=1),labels=c("1$","10$","100$"), col.axis="black",     las=2,cex.axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `pt.cex = 1` inside legend and then you can change `cex` without changing the whole legend size:

Example (cex=1.5):

```
par(font.main=3, font.lab=1, font.sub=1, cex.main=2, cex.lab=1.7, cex.sub=1.2)

plot(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`12.2`)),type="l",col="blue",main="Momentum-Performance Deutschland",ylab="Portfolio Wert",xlab="Jahr",ylim=c(-0.5,2.5),yaxt ="n"
 ,cex.main=1.5,cex.lab=1,cex.axis=1)
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`12.7`)),type="l",col="green")
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$`6.2`)),type="l",col="red")
lines(plot.DE$Monat,cumsum(log10(1+plot.DE$Markt)),type="l",col="yellow")
legend("topleft",legend = c("12-2","12-7","6-2","Markt"),col = c("blue","green","red","yellow"),pt.cex = 1, cex=1.5,adj = c(0, 0.5),lty=1, ,bg="grey",y.intersp = 0.8,x.intersp = 1.2)
axis(2, at=seq(0,2,by=1),labels=c("1$","10$","100$"), col.axis="black",     las=2,cex.axis=1)
```

Comment: read this a few times on stack overflow, however, every time i follow this approach the legend would change in size too: legend("topleft",legend = c("12-2","12-7","6-2","Markt"),col = c("blue","green","red","yellow"),adj = c(0, 0.5),pt.cex = 1,lty=1, cex=0.8,bg="grey",y.intersp = 0.8,x.intersp = 1.2)

Comment: Can you try it without the `adj` bit?

Comment: still the same, the text size increases but so does the legend. Don't want 1/6 of my plot to be the legend :D
Found no solution anywhere :/